# $wpdb->prepare was called incorrectly when inserting multiple records

Tags: wpdb

This works:

```
$values = array();

foreach (  $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%d,%s,%s)", $post_id, $key, $value );
}

$query = "INSERT INTO {$table} (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
$query .= implode( ",\n", $values );
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "$query", $values ) );
```

But it throws this notice:

> PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called **incorrectly**.
> The query does not contain the correct number of placeholders (0) for
> the number of arguments passed (3).

How can I avoid the Notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need the second `$wpdb->prepare()` and just do `$wpdb->query( $query );`. The reason is because the `$query` does not contain any placeholders just as stated in the notice; only the items in `$values` contain the placeholders, but you already prepared them in the `foreach`. Additionally, be sure to run the `query()` only if the array `$values` is not empty.

Comment: As always, thank you.